# Как сделать изменение радиуса 3D объекта по кнопке?

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

Здравствуйте. Есть 3D объект в XAML. Как сделать изменение радиуса 3D объекта по кнопке?

**Добавлено из комментариев**.

```
MeshGeometry3D mesh = new MeshGeometry3D();

int r = int.Parse(textBox.Text);

double dt = ((360.0 / 180.0) * Math.PI) / 100;
double dp = ((180.0 / 180.0) * Math.PI) / 100;

for (int pi = 0; pi <= 100; pi++) {
    double phi = pi * dp;

    for (int ti = 0; ti <= 100; ti++) {
    double theta = ti * dt;

    mesh.Positions.Add(GetPosition(theta, phi, r));
    mesh.Normals.Add((Vector3D) GetPosition(theta, phi, r));
    mesh.TextureCoordinates.Add(new System.Windows.Point(theta / (2 * Math.PI), phi / (Math.PI)));
    }
}

Sp1.Geometry = mesh;

this.Camera.FieldOfView = 6;
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте масштабирование объекта в трехмерной плоскости, а именно класс [ScaleTransform3D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.media3d.scaletransform3d.aspx). По ссылке приведен пример, который показывает использование ScaleTransform3D в качестве преобразования для GeometryModel3D.

Для справки: [общие сведения о трехмерных преобразованиях](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms753347.aspx).

Comment: Масштабирование это ведь не радиус и там диапазон значений другой от 0 до 2. А радиус задается в диапазоне от 1 до 100.

Я делаю так радиус изменяется, но проблема в том что к объекту привязаны ещё другие 3D объектыкоторые расположены на его поверхности и проходят через него один объект изменяется в размерах а другие нет. Как сделать, чтобы изменялись все объекты или подогнать масштаб.

Если в TextBoxе задаю значение радиуса r в пределах от 20 до 30 все работает.

Comment: Если ввожу значения меньше 20 или больше 30, основной объект уменьшается и увеличивается, а те, которые к нему привязаны, остаются висеть в пространстве.